# Regex: Searching for all expressions which will vary in file

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to search and get all the groups in a file (string), in which each group have subdivisions, whose number can vary
so I need to parse all the subdivision in the string.
The string I am trying to parse is:

```
GROUP_DEFN_START
GROUP:REGLOG
HW_REG_OPER "trace hw register operations"
HW_REG_OPER1 "trace hw register operations"
HW_REG_OPER2 "trace hw register operations"
HW_REG_OPER3 "trace hw register operations"
# Add more structs here: <struct name><space>"[<brief description>]"
GROUP:ISRLOG
ISR_STATUS "trace hw isr status"
ISR_STATUS1 "trace hw isr status"
ISR_STATUS2 "trace hw isr status"
ISR_STATUS3 "trace hw isr status"
ISR_STATUS4 "trace hw isr status"
# Add more structs here: <struct name><space>"[<brief description>]"
GROUP:PROCLOG
PROC_STATUS "trace procedure status"
PROC_STATUS1 "trace procedure status"
PROC_STATUS2 "trace procedure status"
PROC_STATUS3 "trace procedure status"
PROC_STATUS4 "trace procedure status"
PROC_STATUS5 "trace procedure status"
# Add more structs here: <struct name><space>"[<brief description>]"
GROUP_DEFN_END
STRUCT=re.split('("(.*?)"\n',group_content[0])
```

I need to get the sub-division of gruops in a 2D-list
like this.............

> `[[HW_REG_OPER,HW_REG_OPER1,HW_REG_OPER2,HW_REG_OPER3],[ISR_STATUS,ISR_STATUS1,ISR_STATUS2,ISR_STATUS3,ISR_STATUS4],[PROC_STATUS,PROC_STATUS1,PROC_STATUS2,PROC_STATUS3,PROC_STATUS4,PROC_STATUS5]].......`

The number of subdivision contents may vary.

```
group_content = re.findall(r'GROUP:(.*?)\n(.*?)GROUP',spec_content, re.M|re.S|re.X)
STRUCT=re.split('("(.*?)"\n',group_content[0])
```

I need to further improve it to get the subdivisions.

Comment: Use: ([A-Z]+_[A-Z_\d]+)\s*\"

Answer (score 1):

You may get all the blocks with the following regex in `re.findall`:

```
(?m)^GROUP:.*((?:\r?\n(?!GROUP:).*)*)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/jt0CDP/2).

**Details**:

- `(?m)^` - start of a line
- `GROUP:` - a literal substring
- `.*` - any 0+ chars up to the end of the *line*
- `((?:\r?\n(?!GROUP:).*)*)` - Group 1 whose contents will be returned with `re.findall`, matching 0+ sequences of:

  - `\r?\n` - a line break (optional CR and a LF)
  - `(?!GROUP:)` - that are not followed with `GROUP:` literal char sequence
  - `.*`   - any 0+ chars other than line break chars

Then, you need to extract the first words at the beginning of lines followed with spaces + `"` with a [`re.findall(r'(?m)^(\w+)\s+\"', block)`](https://regex101.com/r/DYhIDE/1).

- `(?m)^` - line start
- `(\w+)` - Group 1 capturing 1+ word chars
- `\s+\"` - 1+ whitespaces and a `"`.

[Python demo](https://ideone.com/UFmfZa):

```
import re
s = "GROUP_DEFN_START\nGROUP:REGLOG\nHW_REG_OPER \"trace hw register operations\"\nHW_REG_OPER1 \"trace hw register operations\"\nHW_REG_OPER2 \"trace hw register operations\"\nHW_REG_OPER3 \"trace hw register operations\"\n# Add more structs here: <struct name><space>\"[<brief description>]\"\nGROUP:ISRLOG\nISR_STATUS \"trace hw isr status\"\nISR_STATUS1 \"trace hw isr status\"\nISR_STATUS2 \"trace hw isr status\"\nISR_STATUS3 \"trace hw isr status\"\nISR_STATUS4 \"trace hw isr status\"\n# Add more structs here: <struct name><space>\"[<brief description>]\"\nGROUP:PROCLOG\nPROC_STATUS \"trace procedure status\"\nPROC_STATUS1 \"trace procedure status\"\nPROC_STATUS2 \"trace procedure status\"\nPROC_STATUS3 \"trace procedure status\"\nPROC_STATUS4 \"trace procedure status\"\nPROC_STATUS5 \"trace procedure status\"\n# Add more structs here: <struct name><space>\"[<brief description>]\"\nGROUP_DEFN_END"
block_regex = re.compile(r'(?m)^GROUP:.*((?:\r?\n(?!GROUP:).*)*)')
item_regex = re.compile(r'(?m)^(\w+)\s+"')
matches = block_regex.findall(s)
res = []
for m in matches:
    res.append(item_regex.findall(m))
print(res)
```

Output:

```
[
    ['HW_REG_OPER', 'HW_REG_OPER1', 'HW_REG_OPER2', 'HW_REG_OPER3'], 
    ['ISR_STATUS', 'ISR_STATUS1', 'ISR_STATUS2', 'ISR_STATUS3', 'ISR_STATUS4'],
    ['PROC_STATUS', 'PROC_STATUS1', 'PROC_STATUS2', 'PROC_STATUS3', 'PROC_STATUS4', 'PROC_STATUS5']
]
```